# Present ViewController: Page Sheet animation, but faster

Tags: ios, swift, presentviewcontroller

I'd like to make use of the new fancy `Page Sheet` presenting animation in iOS 13, but I'd like to speed it up a bit. Is there a way to lower the duration without implementing a complete custom duration?

I have tried using CATransition, which does not change anything about the animation.

```
let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.05
self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
self.present(presentedVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control all animations speed by setting the `speed` on the window:

```
 window?.layer.speed = 1.5 // or 0.1 to slow motion // `1` is default
```

this means `1.5` times faster than usual.

If you set it on the main `window` of the application, all animations will be affected (like turning on *Slow Animations* option of the simulator)